# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrouge.utils'; 'pyrouge' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this library in my code:

`from pyrouge.utils import log`

But I am getting the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrouge.utils';`
`'pyrouge' is not a package`

Though pyrouge in already installed in my system. I tried to find its solution but there are like none results. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment?

Comment: I am using anaconda with spyder as editor. I used this method to create environment: ```conda create --name myenv```

Comment: Okay, what’s in the environment? Where did you launch Spyder?

Comment: In the model directory.